# Image Refuses to Load, No Faults

Tags: html, css

I'm a new Web Developer and i am wondering why my image doesn't load?
Everything is set up and its linked to a folder so I don't see why I cannot see the image.

I have checked everywhere and only receive useless information!

So, if you can help Thanks!

Code

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .header {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 20px 10px;
    }

    .header a {
      float: left;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 25px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .header a.logo {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .header a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .header a.active {
      background-color: dodgerblue;
      color: white;
    }

    .header-right {
      float: right;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .header a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .header-right {
        float: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <a href="#default" class="logo">Daniel_Dev</a>
    <div class="header-right">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:20px">
    <h1>Looking for a Scripter!</h1>
    <p>Seek no Further you Found Him!</p>
    <p>Hey There!</p>
    <img src="../MyPortfolio/SiteImages/Head.jpeg", alt="Daniel">
    
  </div>

</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: Try putting in the full src address, e.g. starting with http to prove that the image name and type are correct. Then work through your folder structure to ensure you have the relative setting correct.

Comment: Would be nice if you could show your directory structure. Suggest some [tree command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(command))

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and tested it, the issue doesn't seem to be any of the CSS or HTML code, but rather the file path. Are you sure you have the file path correct for the src attribute of the image tag? Do you need to remove the '..' and use a single '.' instead, or just no period at all in the file path name?